# Mac Book Air in a hot car?

Tags: macbook-pro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is putting the computer to sleep while it's in a hot car a bad idea?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50893/is-putting-the-computer-to-sleep-while-its-in-a-hot-car-a-bad-idea)

Are there any published safe temperature ranges for Mac Book Airs?  Is it safe leaving one inside a dark part of a very hot car, think 32°C / 90°F ambient temperature, plus sun and car effects.

Comment: In what country are you living? No thieves? :)

Comment: Cars can get well over 32°C inside during the summer in most parts of the world.

Comment: Do not leave your expensive, desirable, and very portable computer in your car, regardless of heat. Just don't. As an academic exercise, you would probably be pushing the safety limits and ruining your battery life. In the real world, with lots of thieves who would love to have your Mac, just don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Macworld did some tests back in 2008 with heat ranges of the Macbook Air, http://www.macworld.com/article/1132216/mbair_temp.html. I wouldn't risk it though. You never know what could happen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the [Apple tech specs page](http://www.apple.com/macbookair/specs.html) lists:

> Storage temperature: -13° to 113°F (-24° to 45°C)

According to [the National Weather Service](http://www.nws.noaa.gov/os/heat/index.shtml), when the outside temperature is 80°F, a parked car can reach 114°F in 30 minutes.

(Unrelated to the heat, most car insurance policies don't cover theft of items left in a car, so it's probably a bad idea even if the heat was OK.)

Answer (score 0):

It would be fine to LEAVE it in the car, so long as the Macbook wasn't in use. (That way the internals aren't adding even more heat to the mix)